# How do I play a friend's game on my PS4 console?

Tags: ps4

My brother downloaded a game on his ps4 console, and I would like to play that game on my console without buying it myself. Is this possible?

Comment: This would be considered piracy, I feel.  This isn't something we should help with.

Comment: you're brother would need to set his profile up on you're PS4 and change his primary PS4 in his account to be yours rather than his own or you play his console. if he doesn't want to do that (which i would suspect so) you're out of luck

Answer (score -1):

You simply have to sign in as the other users on your PS4. So long as you are logged in, you can play their games on their account. You will have to download the games they bought by going to "Library" and "Purchased". You should see all titles, demos, etc that You and THE OTHER USER have bought, then simply download the ones from their account.

Remember, you must be signed in the whole time to play the game that is on their profile.

Comment: my mistake i misread the answer (i misread the part about who was logging in), my reason now is that your answer implies a user having another users login credentials and i can't imagine why someone who pays for their content would share their account details like that given that it then gives another user free access to their funds

Comment: I know this is old but it's still true, and I, like the Asker, share my account with my brother and vice versa. I can play any of his games on my PS4 as long as I'm signed in as him. I do not have to set my PS4 as his primary. This means all trophies get awarded to his account though.